# How can I change the instrument when writing a MIDI file?

Tags: java, midi

I have used [this](http://www.automatic-pilot.com/midifile.html) template to write a program that writes MIDI files, the only problem I am having now is changing the instrument

This code segment is commented to set the instrument to piano, but I would like to know if there are other instruments I could set it to with different message inputs.

```
//****  set instrument to Piano  ****
    mm = new ShortMessage();
    mm.setMessage(0xC0, 0x00, 0x00);
    me = new MidiEvent(mm,(long)0);
    t.add(me);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other instruments are specified in the [general MIDI standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI), though not all synths are guaranteed to support these sounds.

Also, a MIDI program change message is only 2 bytes, not 3. Looking at the example template code you linked to , it seems that the `setMessage()` method provides the appropriate overrides for this. If you write 3 bytes to this message, then the 3rd byte will be erroneously interpreted as the first byte of the next message.